Refactoring command pattern
I have implemented a command pattern for an SDK that I am building in C# but I want to prevent it from being misused. What I currently have (1) is this. Notice how the request's Execute method can be called directly, bypassing the logic in the SDK Execute method:
 public partial class Sdk
 {
     public async Task<TOut> Execute1<TOut>(ICommandRequest1<TOut> commandRequest)
         where TOut : ICommandResponse1
     {
         // validation logic and other logic goes here
         return await commandRequest.Execute1(this);
     }
 }

 public interface IRequest1 { }
 public interface IResponse1 { }
 public interface ICommandResponse1 : IResponse1 { }

 public interface ICommandRequest1<TOut> : IRequest1
     where TOut : ICommandResponse1
 {
     Task<TOut> Execute1(Sdk sdk);
 }

 public class DeleteOrderResponse1 : ICommandResponse1
 {
     public int OrderNum { get; set; }
 }

 // there are many request objects. this one is for deleting orders.
 public class DeleteOrderRequest1 : ICommandRequest1<DeleteOrderResponse1>
 {
     public int OrderNum { get; set; }

     public async Task<DeleteOrderResponse1> Execute1(Sdk sdk)
     {
         // logic goes here

         return await Task.FromResult(new DeleteOrderResponse1()); // example response
     }
 }

 public class TestItOut1
 {
     public async Task Test()
     {
         var sdk = new Sdk();
         var request = new DeleteOrderRequest1 { OrderNum = 1 };
         var response = await sdk.Execute1(request); // correct usage

         // I do not want to allow this, because it bypasses all the logic in the
         // sdk.Execute1() method
         var response2 = request.Execute1(sdk);
     }
 }

So I thought I could try separating out the request from its execution (2). But this is more cumbersome - there is a lot more plumbing I wish was not there, and especially I don't like having to cast the generic inputRequest to a type inside the new Execute2 method and then cast back again for the return type.
 public partial class Sdk
 {
     public async Task<TOut> Execute2<TOut>(ICommandRequest2<TOut> commandRequest)
         where TOut : class, ICommandResponse2
     {
         // validation logic and other logic goes here
         return await new CommandExecutor2<TOut>().Execute2(commandRequest, this);
     }
 }

 public interface IRequest2 { }
 public interface IResponse2 { }
 public interface ICommandResponse2 : IResponse2 { }

 public interface ICommandExecutor2<TOut> : IRequest2
    where TOut : ICommandResponse2
 {
     Task<TOut> Execute2(ICommandRequest2<TOut> request, Sdk sdk);
 }

 public interface ICommandRequest2<TOut> : IRequest2
     where TOut : ICommandResponse2
 {
     //note: no longer contains the Execute method - good
 }

 public class DeleteOrderResponse2 : ICommandResponse2
 {
     public int OrderNum { get; set; }
 }
 public class DeleteOrderRequest2 : ICommandRequest2<DeleteOrderResponse2>
 {
     public int OrderNum { get; set; }
 }

 // there are many command executors. this one is for deleting orders.
 // note: internal - so clients outside the SDK cannot access this
 internal class CommandExecutor2<TOut> : ICommandRequest2<DeleteOrderResponse2>, ICommandExecutor2<TOut>
     where TOut : class, ICommandResponse2
 {
     public async Task<TOut> Execute2(ICommandRequest2<TOut> inputRequest, Sdk sdk)
     {
         // I don't like having to do a cast here
         DeleteOrderRequest2 request = inputRequest as DeleteOrderRequest2;

         // logic goes here

         // I also don't like having to do a cast here
         return (await Task.FromResult(new DeleteOrderResponse2())) as TOut; // example response
     }
 }

 public class TestItOut2
 {
     public async Task Test()
     {
         var sdk = new Sdk();
         var request = new DeleteOrderRequest2 { OrderNum = 1 };
         DeleteOrderResponse2 response = await sdk.Execute2(request);

         // this no longer works - good - clients will not be able to bypass the validation logic
         // var response2 = request.Execute2(sdk);
     }
 }

Does anyone have any better ideas for solving the problem? I don't want to use reflection or if/switch statements. Ideally I would like to make CommandExecutor2 use concrete types DeleteOrderRequest2 and DeleteOrderResponse2 but I haven't had any luck with that so far.

You might have more success with your question over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

In the end the solution turned out to be quite simple - just make the commands members of 2 interfaces - 1 public one that does not contain an ExecuteCommand() method, and one internal one that does contain an ExecuteCommand() method. Then the SDK will accept the public interface in its ExecuteSdk() method, and immediately convert that object to the internal interface to use the ExecuteCommand() method internally.
Assembly 1 - client:
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task CanCreateOrder()
        {
            var sdk = new Sdk();
            var createOrderRequest = new CreateOrderRequest();
    
            // note: createOrderRequest.Execute() does not exist in this assembly - good
            // this means the client cannot bypass sdk.ExecuteSdk()
            // createOrderRequest.Execute();
    
            // but sdk.ExecuteSdk does exist in this assembly - exactly as I want
            var createOrderResponse = await sdk.ExecuteSdk(createOrderRequest);
    
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(createOrderResponse, typeof(CreateOrderResponse));
            Assert.AreEqual(createOrderResponse.OrderId, 1234);
            Assert.AreEqual(createOrderResponse.Status, "success");
        }
    }

Assembly 2 - SDK:
public class Sdk
{
    public async Task<TOut> ExecuteSdk<TOut>(ICommandRequest<TOut> commandRequest)
        where TOut : ICommandResponse
    {
        // validation logic and other logic goes here
        return await ((IInternalCommandRequest<TOut>)commandRequest).ExecuteCommand(this);
    }
}

public interface IResponse { }
public interface ICommandResponse : IResponse { }

public interface ICommandRequest<TOut>
    where TOut : ICommandResponse
{
    // note: do not expose the ExecuteCommand() method here, otherwise it will be public
    // and can be called directly by users of this SDK, bypassing the validations in the
    // Sdk.ExecuteSdk() methods
}

internal interface IInternalCommandRequest<TOut>
    where TOut : ICommandResponse
{
    // note: do define the ExecuteCommand() method here, only to be used internally by
    // the SDK
    Task<TOut> ExecuteCommand(Sdk sdk);
}

public class CreateOrderResponse : ICommandResponse
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

// there are many request objects. this one is for creating orders.
public class CreateOrderRequest : IInternalCommandRequest<CreateOrderResponse>, ICommandRequest<CreateOrderResponse>
{
    async Task<CreateOrderResponse> IInternalCommandRequest<CreateOrderResponse>.ExecuteCommand(Sdk sdk)
    {
        // logic goes here
        var createOrderResponse = new CreateOrderResponse
        {
            OrderId = 1234,
            Status = "success"
        };
        return await Task.FromResult(createOrderResponse); // example response
    }
}

public class DeleteOrderResponse : ICommandResponse
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteOrderRequest : IInternalCommandRequest<DeleteOrderResponse>, ICommandRequest<DeleteOrderResponse>
{
    async Task<DeleteOrderResponse> IInternalCommandRequest<DeleteOrderResponse>.ExecuteCommand(Sdk sdk)
    {
        // logic goes here
        return await Task.FromResult(new DeleteOrderResponse { Status = "failed"}); // example response
    }
}


This is closer to what I want, and simpler. Modified from here.
However it still doesn't return the correct type at build-time - I want DeleteOrderResponse instead of IResponse. Its annoying for the client to have to cast this themself.
And I also don't want the extra step of creating a DeleteOrderCommand for the client. The SDK should take care of this.
public class TestItOut
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Sdk sdk = new Sdk();

        Request request = new Request { OrderNum = "1234" };
        AbstractCommand command = new DeleteOrderCommand(request);

        var response = (DeleteOrderResponse)sdk.ExecuteSdkCommand(command);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractCommand
{
    protected Request request;

    // Constructor

    public AbstractCommand(Request request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public abstract IResponse Execute();
}

public interface IResponse { }
public class DeleteOrderResponse : IResponse
{
}

public class CreateOrderResponse : IResponse
{
}

/// <summary>
/// The 'ConcreteCommand' class
/// </summary>
public class DeleteOrderCommand : AbstractCommand
{
    public DeleteOrderCommand(Request request) : base(request)
    {
    }

    public override DeleteOrderResponse Execute()
    {
        string orderNum = request.OrderNum;
        // do logic here
        return new DeleteOrderResponse();
    }
}
public class CreateOrderCommand : AbstractCommand
{
    public CreateOrderCommand(Request request) : base(request)
    {
    }

    public override CreateOrderResponse Execute()
    {
        string orderNum = request.OrderNum;
        // do logic here
        return new CreateOrderResponse();
    }
}

public class Request
{
    public string OrderNum { get; set; }
}

public class Sdk
{
    public IResponse ExecuteSdkCommand(AbstractCommand command)
    {
        return command.Execute();
    }
}


I slept on it and came up with a solution that works how I want it to.
A few key points:

The type of the response is wrapped up in the request interface. This way there is no need for the client to cast the response out of an interface to a concrete type when it receives it back.
The requirements was that I did not want the client to be able to execute the command itself. To achieve this, the request objects cannot contain any references to the command class - since the request object is public. So I used an internal class for the commands and overloaded a commonly named method with an input argument of the request types. There may be other ways of doing this that are better? It would be nice not to have to use dynamic to get the IRequest<TOut> to recognise either DeleteOrderRequest or CreateOrderRequest. Anyway, it works.

    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    
    namespace Hack6;
    
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        private Sdk sdk;
        public Tests()
        {
            this.sdk = new Sdk();
        }
    
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanCreateOrder()
        {
            var createOrderRequest = new CreateOrderRequest();
            var createOrderResponse = this.sdk.ExecuteSdk(createOrderRequest);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(createOrderResponse, typeof(CreateOrderResponse));
            Assert.AreEqual(createOrderResponse.OrderId, "1234");
            Assert.AreEqual(createOrderResponse.Status, "success");
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanDeleteOrder()
        {
            var sdk = new Sdk();
            var deleteOrderRequest = new DeleteOrderRequest { OrderNum = "1234" };
            var deleteOrderResponse = this.sdk.ExecuteSdk(deleteOrderRequest);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(deleteOrderResponse, typeof(DeleteOrderResponse));
            Assert.AreEqual(deleteOrderResponse.Status, "deleted");
        }
    }
    
    public interface IResponse { }
    
    public class DeleteOrderResponse : IResponse
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CreateOrderResponse : IResponse
    {
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    
    public interface IRequest<TOut> where TOut : IResponse
    {
    }
    
    public class DeleteOrderRequest : IRequest<DeleteOrderResponse>
    {
        public string OrderNum { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CreateOrderRequest : IRequest<CreateOrderResponse>
    {
    }
    
    public class Sdk
    {
        public TOut ExecuteSdk<TOut>(IRequest<TOut> request)
            where TOut : IResponse
        {
            var commands = new Commands();
            var response = commands.ExecuteCommand((dynamic)request);
            return response;
        }
    }
    
    internal class Commands
    {
        public DeleteOrderResponse ExecuteCommand(DeleteOrderRequest request)
        {
            // logic goes here
            return new DeleteOrderResponse { Status = "deleted" };
        }
    
        public CreateOrderResponse ExecuteCommand(CreateOrderRequest request)
        {
            // logic goes here
            return new CreateOrderResponse
            {
                OrderId = "1234",
                Status = "success"
            };
        }
    }


